# iPhone new SDK (4.2) and plist on the device re-initialized

Tags: iphone, plist, ios-4.2

I've just updated XCode with the new SDK 4.2 and launched my app in my development environment, I see the app is asking me to register again: registration is a process I do once for the new users and I save the info in a plist.

Why it is asking me to do it again? I suppose for the new path of the plist or something.

Do the app's user see the same behavior? I hope not it would be a great problem to me!

I don't remember this behavior on the previous releases.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Is that plist file part of the XCode project?  If it is, it was probably overwritten when you built the new version of the app onto your device.  That is why you got the registration again.

Your users would have the same experience, I am guessing.

Comment: Yes plist is part of the project, located in the document folder of the iPhone.

Comment: In the plist there're user account settings, I don't understand why the new build should overwrite it. If what you say it's true I realize plist it's not good to store info.

Comment: I've looked at the directories in \Application Support\iPhone Simulator and I see all the previous sdk with all the build. I hope it's something related to the simulator not to the device. It's a no sense delete and recreate a new Documents folder after a new firmware update, imho.

Comment: Take a read of this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10 I think that will explain where you need to store information that should persist between versions.

Comment: Just for your information. After releasing new version nothing happened to the users and everything still working fine with the plist. I think it's something related on the development environment. Thanx Fabrizio